# VUE 2 - process.env variable is undefined

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, dotenv

In my Vue 2 app I have a `.env` file with the following variables

```
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3001/api
VUE_APP_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3001
```

In my component the `VUE_APP_API_URL` logs correctly but the `VUE_APP_BASE_URL` is undefined.

```
  mounted() {
    console.log('API -> ', process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL)
    console.log('BASE -> ', process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL) // undefined
  }
```

If anyone knows what is going wrong here I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: There's no explanation. Both should be available.  Even if it were overriden, it wouldn't be undefined. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. It's possible that you didn't restart dev server or else

Comment: Are you using Vite? If so use `import.meta.env.VUE_APP_API_URL` instead.